# Convert list to hashmap

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, collections

Title of the question may give you the impression that it is duplicate question, but according to me it is not.

I am just a few months old in Java and a month old in MongoDB, SpringBoot and REST.

I have a Mongo Collection with 3 fields in a document, **_id (default field), appName and appKey**. I am using **list** to iterate through all the documents and find one document whose appName and appKey matches with the one that is passed. This collection right now has only 4 entries, and thus it is running smoothly. But I was reading a bit about collections and found that if there will be a higher number of documents in a collection then the result with **list** will be much slower than **hashMap**.

But as I have already said that I am quite new to Java, I am having a bit of trouble converting my code to **hashMap**, so I was hoping if someone can guide me through this.

I am also attaching my code for reference.

```
public List<Document> fetchData() {
    // Collection that stores appName and appKey
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("info");
    List<Document> nameAndKeyList = new ArrayList<Document>();

    // Getting the list of appName and appKey from info DB
    AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection
            .aggregate(Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id",
                    new BasicDBObject("_id", "$id").append("appName", "$appName").append("appKey", "$appKey"))

    )));
    for (Document doc : output) {

        nameAndKeyList.add((Document) doc.get("_id"));

    }
    return nameAndKeyList;

}// End of Method
```

And then I am calling it in another method of the same class:

```
List<Document> nameAndKeyList = new ArrayList<>();

        //InfoController is the name of the class
        InfoController obj1 = new InfoController();
        nameAndKeyList = obj1.fetchData();

        // Fetching and checking if the appName & appKey pair
        // is present in the DB one by one.
        // If appName & appKey mismatches, it increments the value
        // of 'i' and check them with the other values in DB
        for (int i = 0; i < nameAndKeyList.size(); i++) {

           "followed by my code"
```

And if I am not wrong then there will be no need for the above loop also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see any `map` implementation there? where you want to add?

Comment: Hi, @FlyingZombie. I want to use **hashMap** in place of **list**. Is there something I am missing or I need to know?

Comment: How many elements are you foreseeing you will have in the list? Asking because what you have said until now does not convince me you will have a problem with it being too slow.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thousands of elements. That is the only reason I want to switch.

Comment: `List` is an interface (one of its implementations is `ArrayList`) while `HashMap` is one of the implementations of the `Map` interface, not necessarily the most performing in all situations, so if your concern is performance you should look also at the other implementations of `Map` to determine the best one for your case. However chances are that after implementing that and measuring the performance gain you will be disappointed; thousands of elements is not much at all, it's very possible that the speed difference will be unnoticeable.

Comment: @SantiBailors Okay. But in future, I may have more and more elements so I want to play it safe, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help, without which I would not have got to a solution.

```
public HashMap<String, String> fetchData() {

    // Collection that stores appName and apiKey
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("info");

    HashMap<String, String> appKeys = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Getting the list of appName and appKey from info DB
    AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection
            .aggregate(Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id",
                    new BasicDBObject("_id", "$id").append("appName", "$appName").append("appKey", "$appKey"))

    )));

    String appName = null;
    String appKey = null;

    for (Document doc : output) {

        Document temp = (Document) doc.get("_id");

        appName = (String) temp.get("appName");
        appKey = (String) temp.get("appKey");
        appKeys.put(appName, appKey);

    }
    return appKeys;
```

Calling the above method into another method of the same class.

```
InfoController obj = new InfoController();

            //Fetching the values of 'appName' & 'appKey' sent from 'info' DB
            HashMap<String, String> appKeys = obj.fetchData();

            storedAppkey = appKeys.get(appName);

            //Handling the case of mismatch
            if (storedAppkey == null || storedApikey.compareTo(appKey)!=0)
            {//Then the response and further processing that I need to do.
```

Now what HashMap has done is that it has made my code more readable and the 'for' loop that I was using for iterating is gone, although it might not make much difference in the performance as of now.

Thanks once again to everyone for your help and support.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a simple find query to get the record you need directly from Mongo DB.

```
Document document = collection
            .find(new Document("appName", someappname).append("appKey", someappkey)).first();
```

Comment: On one hand, if it’s fast enough, it’s a simple solution. On the other, if it isn’t, I would expect you could do it faster in Java. You are perfectly right, there is no reason to limit oneself to solutions in Java.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a list is not much slower or faster than an HashMap. A Hasmap is commonly used to save key-pair values such as "ID", "Name" or something like that. In your case I see you are using ArrayList without a specified size for the list. better use a linked list when you do not know the size because an arraylist is holding a array behind and extending this by copying. If you want to generate a Hasmap out of the List or use a Hasmap you need to map an ID and the value to the records.

```
HashMap<String /*type of the identifier*/, String /*type of value*/> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
for (Document doc : output) {
        map.put(doc.get("_id"), doc.get("_value"));
}
```

Comment: Do not switch to `LinkedList` unless your measurements show it’s faster. My suspicion is it will be slower. It will surely take up more space.

Comment: @Code.IT, is it not the case that in searching fields of a document (if there are a million field) then hashMap will be much faster as ArrayList performance is O(n) compared to HashMap's O(1)?

Comment: In case you do not know the size of your list and it can extend up to much more than 10 records LinkedList is prefered. As you did not understand I said: An ArrayList should not be used when you do not know the size of the content!

Comment: Hi, @Code.IT. Thanks, but my main problem was that what should I do with `AggregateIterable<Document> output `, as I tried to use **map** instead of **Array.asList**, but was not able to get it right somehow.

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid premature optimization (lookup the expression if you don’t know what it is). Put a realistic number of thousands of items containing near-realistic data in your list. Try to retrieve an item that isn’t there. This will force your `for` loop to traverse the entire list. See how long it takes. Try a number of times to get an impression of whether you get impatient. If you don’t, you’re done.

If you find out that you need a speed-up, I agree that `HashMap` is one of the obvious solutions to try. One of the first things to consider with this is a key type for you `HashMap`. As I understand, what you need to search for is an item where `appName` and `appKey` are both right. The good solution is to write a simple class with these two fields and `equals` and `hashCode` methods (I’ll call it `DocumentHashMapKey` for now, think of a better name). For `hashCode()`, try `Objects.hash(appName, appKey)`. If it doesn’t give satisfactory performance with the data you have, consider alternatives. Now you are ready to build your `HashMap< DocumentHashMapKey, Document>`.

If you’re lazy or just want a first impression of how a `HashMap` performs, you may also build your keys by concatenating `appName + "$@@" + appKey` (where the string in the middle is something that is unlikely to be part of a name or key) and use `HashMap<String, Document>`.

Everything I said can be refined depending on your needs. This was just to get you started.